# CMS pages do not displaying images in admin panel

Tags: content-management-system, magento

I have a weird problem with magento cms module.

All the CMS pages on the frontend are displaying images correctly, but images are not displaying on the admin cms editor page. It just displays 'X' image broken icon.

I actually don't know where to start to fix this issue.

Any one had similar issue?

Answer (score 4):

If in frontend you have the file http://yourdomain.com/media/your_file.jpg which renders perfectly, when editing the content in backend that file is linked through smtg like http://*yourdomain.com*/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/key/b9f80b36bc860a90ea2a03b61a6babfa/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9InBvd2RlcnNfOTB4OTAuanBnIn19/ and this image is broken.

The problem is that in Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_WysiwygController (Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php) method directiveAction the $url is ... an url (of course) instead of an image path which is what we need in this case.

You can create a module that overwrites the directiveAction and you would need to replace the $url assignment to 
$url = BP . str_replace(Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('web/unsecure/base_url'),"/", Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->filter($directive) );

hope that works for you,
Ky.

Comment: Do you know of any modules that correct this issue? Seems like an annoying bug!

Comment: This is still a problem ! Anybody got it fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the following in your admin :

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Content Management -> Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog` to `Yes`

This setting is present in 1.7.0.2 at least.